# Recovering data from corrupted macbook pro SSD (PLEASE HELP)

Tags: mac, ssd, data-recovery

Recently my Mac had one of the most costly issues I've ever had with apple... it's a 2019 16' MacBook pro (there are no other variants for that year)

the laptop drained the battery and shut down, and ever since my attempts to start mac os were unsuccessful, I'm stuck in an infinite boot loop however this is not the normal infinite boot since nothing like recovery/network recovery or even t2 revive works...

Strangely my windows Bootcamp seems to work fine, I am able to choose that boot and it will work.

after taking it to several technicians I found out that somehow one of the SSD chips that are soldered on the logic board is not responsive, in other words, one of the 4 chips that comprise my SSD is gone, and it just happens that not a byte of my windows partition was on that piece... however since the rest of the memory is fragmented across 3 chips and belongs to mac os now it is completely corrupted and data loss is inevitable...

from bootcamp this is what i see ....[image]

744GB of memory is completely unusable, while before I could see that this is an `apfs` partition...

[image]

Now all I want is to somehow try and recover data from what's left since I have a lot of private keys there that I cannot recover anymore, those have access to source repositories I work with and many other things that I doubt I can easily recover.

Is there some way to read out the contents of the partition and try to make sense of what data is still intact? I used to be doing something like that recovering bit by bit from some hacky bootable CDs but it was many many years ago and who has CDs anymore...

Or at least can I somehow backup this "unused unformatted" space of storage so I can do that later and let people fix my machine... all of this causing so much chaos for my work is unreal.

Comment: Windows has no clue what APFS is, so you won't fix it from there. Stop trying to get anything in Windows to fix it, you'll just make things worse. Get hold of another Mac & connect in Target Disk Mode - https://support.apple.com/en-md/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac - & see what you can see. Apple will fix it, but they won't rescue your data - that was your responsibility to keep a proper backup strategy.

Comment: i know whats my responsibility and i have a backup that has the most important stuff, its the data that i dont yet know that is important that i want to avoid erazing...

my question is about 1. how to backup/copy over unformated raw bytes, 2. how to try and recover intact files from such blob of bytes given we know its apfs....

Comment: no apples brilliant recovery tools and target disc mode do not even launch

Comment: If you can't get into Recovery or TDM, then you're down to a raw recovery attempt by a data recovery specialist. You can't install [or even work] in the Windows partition, because SSDs don't have fixed partition boundaries like HDs do. Any writes to the drive may overwrite parts of the corrupted structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe photorec and testdisk by cgsecurity support the MAC file system.
You could try that.
However, if that fails a recovery service like drive savers might be able to help.  There service are generally very expensive, and can easily cost more than $900.